# What do you call a brand/logo panel that a company often carries along to a trade show?

Tags: word-choice

Let say there is a company named BlueEvin. The company has an object made of plastic or wood that shows the name BlueEvin. The object could be the size of a PC keyboard or smaller. The company often carries that object to a trade show or a conference and puts it on their table so that potential customers can know the name of that company.

I call it a brand/logo panel, but I think there is a better term for it.

So, what do you call the object like a brand/logo panel that a company often carries along to a trade show?

Comment: There may be a more _specific_ term, but this would be an example of **signage**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generically, it's a **table-top display sign** and would be part of a **trade show display**. There are many designs- L-shaped, or convex like this one:

[image]

The kind of trade shows that are more like conferences with small low-key booths that consist mostly of a draped table and some signs are sometimes called "table-top shows" to distinguish them from big high-budget trade shows with enormous custom-designed booths.

Comment: Can you support these contentions, Spehro Pefhany. If so, edit that support into your answer. It will significantly improve this answer and increase the likelihood of more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this should be smaller than a [Sandwich board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich_board).
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich_board)

So more like a [Standing Desk Sign](http://www.officesigncompany.com/office_desk_signs.aspx)?
(http://www.officesigncompany.com/office_desk_signs.aspx)

Comment: This site recommends citation of links & sources in plain text due to the ever-present threat of link-rot.

Answer (score 0):

What do you call an object **1**) the size of a PC keyboard or smaller; **2**) a company carries to a trade show and puts on their table **3**) so that potential customers know the name of that company. **4**) I call it a brand/logo panel

Although these objects are commercially marketed nowadays as “*table-top display signs*,” as documented by Spehro Pefhany, they are also referred to as ***placards*** and ***posters***.

> [**placard**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/placard) *noun*: **1**. A sign or notice for display in a public place. 2. A small card or plaque, such as a nameplate on a door. synonyms: notice, poster, sign, bill, advertisement; see, the Free Dictionary
>
> [**placard**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=placard&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) late 15c., "formal document authenticated by an affixed seal," from Middle French *placquard* "official document with a large, flat seal," also "plate of armor," from Old French *plaquier* "to lay on, cover up, plaster over," from Middle Dutch *placken* "to patch (a garment), to plaster," related to Middle High German *placke* "patch, stain," German *Placken* "spot, patch." ***Meaning "poster" first recorded 1550s in English***; this sense is in Middle French from 15c.; see, etymonline
>
> [**poster**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poster) *noun*: **1**. a placard or bill posted or intended for posting in a public place, as for advertising. see, Dictionary.com
>
> [**poster**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=poster&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   (n.) "bill, placard, thing posted," 1838, from post (v.1). Poster
>   boy/girl/child "someone given prominence in certain causes" is
>   attested by 1990, in reference to fund-raising drives for charities
>   associated with disability, featuring child sufferers, a feature since
>   1930s. see, etymonline
>
> [**plaque**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=plaque&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   (n.) 1848, "ornamental plate or tablet," from French plaque "metal
>   plate, coin" (15c.), perhaps through Flemish placke "small coin," from
>   Middle Dutch placke "disk, patch, stain," related to German Placken
>   "spot, patch" (compare placard). Meaning "deposit on walls of
>   arteries" is first attested 1891; that of "bacteria deposits on teeth"
>   is 1898. see, etymonline